# Inserting a javascript variable into onclick window.open

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert a JavaScript variable into an href, and make it open in a new window.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="https://example.com" onclick="window.open(this.href+'?VALUE='+testVALUE;, '_blank'); return false;">Click Here</a>

<script>
var testVALUE = '1AB56';
</script>
```

The URL should look like this:
https://example.com?VALUE=1AB56

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's a `;` in the middle of the argument you pass to `window.open`. Just after `testVALUE`

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte THANK YOU! Make your comment an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte,  just removing the semicolon will not solve the problem, it will also take user to example.com and open example.com?value=something in another tab. so you'll have to stop propogation of the event.

Comment: @DagaArihant Sorry, I should of specified that I'm also using `return false;` - I just added that to my question.

Comment: Hmm I wonder why I'm getting downvoted. I wish I knew why so I can improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `;` in the middle of the argument you pass to `window.open`. Just after `testVALUE`

Answer (score -1):

Also it's happening because there is no event.preventdefault(); so the browser is acting on it and taking you to the url example.com. 
so something like this should work..

```
<a href="www.example.com" onclick="testme(this,event)">Click Here</a>

<script>
var testVALUE = '1AB56';
var elem;
function testme(ele,event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(ele);
    elem=ele;
    window.open(elem.href+'?VALUE='+testVALUE,'_blank');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: @NickyTheWretch, can u please tell me the reason for downvoting this,i think this is a right answer to your question.